# boto sns - publish many

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sns

We're using boto for push notification to APN/GCM.
In case we want to publish 100 push notifications (different message/badge on each) in a single transmission, can it been done?

currently we call 100 times:

```
push_result = sns_conn.publish(message=message_json, target_arn=endpoint_arn, message_structure='json')
```

instead it could be something like:

```
push_result = sns_conn.publish_many(all_push_data)
```

where all_push_data is the collection of 100 push notifications data:

```
all_push_data = [dict(message=<m1>,target_arn=<t1>,message_structure=<s1>),
                 dict(message=<m2>,target_arn=<t2>,message_structure=<s2>),

                 dict(message=<m100>,target_arn=<t100>,message_structure=<s100>),
                ]
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is rhetorical, by the author's admission (see answer comment).  [Such questions](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question) are asked to make a point rather than elicit an answer, and are unproductive here.

Comment: it is a question. we hope someone has a solution in future boto versions that we're not releases.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can now batch up to 10 SNS messages at once.

```
publish_batch(**kwargs)
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish_batch

Comment: it is about time..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SNS does not provide a bulk publish command.  You can only publish one message to one topic ARN at a time.

Comment: Actually, it was a rhetoric question..we know there is no option. waiting for improvement on this side.